# In Jetpack Compose, Does paddingFromBaseline alter the padding of a Text element?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, padding, android-jetpack-compose-modifier

```
@Composable
fun Sample(){
    val startPadding = 10.dp
    Column {
        Text(
            text = "sample text",
            modifier = Modifier
                .paddingFromBaseline(top = 30.dp)
                .padding(start = startPadding)
        )
        Text(
            text = "sample text",
            modifier = Modifier.padding(start = startPadding)
        )
    }
}
```

The above `Composable` contains two `Text` elements arranged vertically in a `Column`. Both `Text` elements have the same value set for their `start` `padding`. The preview is below

[image: code preview 1]

something weird happens when the `paddingFromBaseline` is set after `padding` i.e

```
@Composable
fun Sample(){
    val startPadding = 10.dp
    Column {
        Text(
            text = "sample text",
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(start = startPadding)
                .paddingFromBaseline(top = 30.dp)
        )
        Text(
            text = "sample text",
            modifier = Modifier.padding(start = startPadding)
        )
    }
}
```

[image: code preview 2]

The `padding` before the first `Text` seems to have doubled, is this a bug or a feature?

I'm under the impression that the order in which `Modifier` `methods` are called doesn't matter so the extra `padding` shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 0):

I no longer see this issue you mention on the emulator or preview. The `.padding(start=` should add padding to the start. The `paddingFromBaseline(top=` should add padding from Baseline (ie) you should see top padding getting added. This is the output of your code that I see

[image]

> I'm under the impression that the order in which Modifier methods are called doesn't matter so the extra padding shouldn't be there.

No. The order of the Modifier methods MATTER and you should be concise when you chain your Modifier methods. [Refer the official doc](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/compose/modifiers#order-modifier-matters)